# Using stack in python gives NoneType error

Tags: python, python-2.7, stack

I am trying to push an item on to stack in Python. Below is the code for trying to push the item :

```
class Search
def generalGraphSearch(problem,fringe):
closed=set()
    #If no nodes
    if problem.isGoalState(problem.getStartState()):
        return problem.getStartState()
    #Create object of Stack class
    stackOb = util.Stack()
    """Push the starting node into the stack. The parameter is the state"""
    stackOb.push(problem.getStartState())
    print stackOb.push(problem.getStartState())

The stack implementation is as below :
class Stack:
    "A container with a last-in-first-out (LIFO) queuing policy."
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def push(self,item):
        "Push 'item' onto the stack"
        self.list.append(item)
```

The print statement in the Search class gives type as none

Any suggestions how to overcome this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the result of `push()` method call, but the method *does not return anything* - that's why you see `None` printed.

Instead, you meant to either explore the contents of the `list` attribute:

```
stackOb.push(problem.getStartState())
print(stackOb.list)
```

or, implement and use the `pop()` method to get the element from the top of the stack:

```
class Stack:
    # ...

    def pop(self):
        return self.list.pop()
```

You can also have a `peek()` method that would simply return the top element from the stack without removing it:

```
class Stack:
    # ...

    def peek(self):
        return self.list[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It helped

Comment: @user6622569 okay, sure, see if you can accept the answer, thanks.